# Error in Removal of Duplicates from a Sorted Array in C++ using Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, pointers, duplicates

I have a task to remove the duplicates from a sorted array.

However, when I try this it doesn't remove anything and still gives me the same values in the output as the original.

I think I'm missing something in the `removeDuplicates()` function.

Also pointer notation would be recommended. Thank you!

```
void removeDuplicates(int *arr, int *size)
{
    int s,*p,i,k=0;
    p=arr;
    s=*size;
    int arr1[s];
    for(i=0;i<s-1;i++)
    {
        if (*(p+i)!=*(p+i+1))
        {
            arr1[k++]=*(p+i);
        }
    }
    arr1[k++]=*(p+s-1);

    for(i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        *(p+i) = arr1[i];
    }
    for(i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        cout<<*(p+i)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the duplicates always adjacent to each other? Also any reason for writing `*(p + i)` rather than just `p[i]` itself?

Comment: Do you have a reason not to use: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique ?

Comment: @Zoso the title says "sorted array", so the duplicates should be adjacent if it's sorted properly.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oh right. I missed the title. The question body had no mention of the array being sorted. Thanks.

Comment: `int arr1[s]` is not valid C++, although some compilers may support it as a non-standard extension (keyword: VLA). If you want a dynamically allocated array, consider using a vector. (Note: this is not the problem, if it compiles, it works, it's just not something you should be relying on)

Comment: What's `arr1[k++] = *(p + s - 1);` supposed to accomplish? I think you should remove this line.

Comment: Or more accurately you should do the last element only once after the loop (if the last element of the input array is different from the last element of the deduplicated array, copy it).

Comment: Recommendation: Save yourself future problems and don't write alphabet soup code. Give the variables descriptive names.

Comment: Note: On the two major compilers I know of that support VLAs `int arr1[s] = {};` doesn't initialize the array quite the way you may be expecting.

Comment: @dratenik **arr1[k++] = *(p + s - 1);**  I'm storing the last element as whether it is unique or repeated, it hasn't stored previously

Comment: should you be doing that inside the loop that runs for each element?

Comment: yeah It should be outside that loop...thanks...but it's still not generating the correct output. @dratenik

Comment: "not generating the correct output" as a problem statement may be overestimating the accuracy of our crystal balls. Can you provide an example of input vs. output (possibly also expected output)?

Comment: Input Parameters
9
1
1
1
-2
-2
-2
3
3
3
Expected Output
1
-2
3
My Output
1
-2
3
1
-2
3
-2
-2
-2
3
3
3
  @dratenik

Comment: Because you're also expected to modify `*size` and you didn't do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters variable length arrays as the array declared in your function

```
int arr1[s] = {};
```

is not a standard C++ feature. And moreover in C where variable length arrays exist you may not initialize them in their declarations.

Moreover if the source array contains only one or two different elements then the value of the variable `k` will be incorrect and equal to either `0` (instead of `1`) or 1 (instead of `2`).

Apart from this the function shall not output anything. It is the caller of the function decides whether to output the sub-array of unique elements. And as the second parameter is passed by reference in C meaning then it shall be changed within the function.

There is standard algorithm `std::unique` that can be used to do the task. Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    
    auto last = std::unique( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );
    
    for ( auto first = std::begin( a ); first != last; ++ first )
    {
        std::cout << *first << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

If you want to write a similar function for arrays yourself using pointers within the function then it can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
size_t removeDuplicates( T *a, size_t n )
{
    T *dest = a;
    
    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        ++dest;
        for ( T *current = a; ++current != a + n;  )
        {
            if ( *current != *( dest - 1 ) )
            {
                if ( dest != current )
                {
                    *dest = *current;
                }
                
                ++dest;
            }
        }           
    }
    
    return dest - a;
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    
    size_t last = removeDuplicates( a, N );
    
    for ( size_t first = 0; first != last; ++first )
    {
        std::cout << a[first] << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Why control `*dest = *current`?

Comment: @greybeard What is unclear with this assignment statement?

Comment: *I* see good reason to have it executed *only when `dest != current`* (which I asked about). Does Gkp? Why ***do** you* not assign unconditionally?

Comment: @greybeard If there are no duplicate elements then the assignments will be redundant and in general inefficient.